# Problem 1.6 in Edwards multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, functions, vector-spaces

The problem requires a proof that if $S$ is a set and $\mathscr{F}(S, \mathbb{R})$ is the set of all functions $S \to \mathbb{R}$, then $\mathscr{F}(S, \mathbb{R})$ is a vector space.

Let $f, g: S \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions. Then $f, g$ lie in $\mathscr{F}(S, \mathbb{R})$.
But then
$$(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$$
for all $x$
in $S$
and
$$(af)(x) = af(x)$$
for all $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$
and all $x$ in $S$.
Moreover, there is a function $h$ such that $h(x) = 0$ for all $x$ in $S$. Last, $1\cdot f(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $S$. So I have completed the proof?

Comment: What do you need to verify for that set to be a vector space?

Comment: Yep, closed with respect to addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: That's not all, but it's a start. I suggest you begin by typing into the question all that you need to prove and then pinpoint what troubles you.

Comment: Very good. Now you have to show that the vector space axioms are satisfied.

Comment: These axioms are almost trivially satisfied, but the exercise asks to show them in order to give a complete proof. For example $a(f+g) = af+ag$ clearly holds, since pointwise we have $a(f(x)+g(x)) = af(x)+ag(x)$, and so on.

Comment: I see. So may I just write: Following from the properties of real numbers?

Comment: @Kurt In additions to the axioms listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition), you need to verify that $\mathscr{F}(S, \mathbb{R})$ is closed for $+_{\mathscr{F}(S, \mathbb{R})}$ and multiplication by scalars. You're missing many things.